# Checking Automapper usage via Roslyn

Tags: c#, automapper, roslyn

I have a generic method defined as below that wraps a call to AutoMapper.

```
public TOut CreateRequest<TOut, TModelIn>(TModelIn data)
{
  ...
  return Mapper.Map<TModelIn, TOut>();
}
```

If I call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid` then I can check that my maps are setup correctly, however I have no way of checking is someone added a line of code to attempt a Map when no Map had been defined.

So I would like to be able to scan my assembly and locate all of the calls to the above method, extract the generic types being used, then hookup those types into a `Mapper.Map<Type1, Type2>();` call. Then I can call the `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid` method, and ensure that all of the Maps in my code have indeed been mapped and are valid.

The idea is to add this into a UnitTest so that I can be sure of the mappings before I get a user to go and test it to see what happens.

**[Update]**
I have been looking at using Roslyn from inside my unit test to do this. Does anyone know how to find the invocation of a method via Roslyn, both a direct invocation, and via a argument list?

Comment: you can do regex in visual studio's find all method (or be lazy and just find all of 'CreateRequest<')

Comment: I need this to run automatically inside the unit test, not be run manually.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the code you can change. Can you modify the generic method or not? If you can, I would suggest to enable a autotest feature, embedded into the method. I can try to elaborate an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve this via `Rosyln`, however it wasn't an easy thing to do.
I ended up loading all documents in my solution, searching through them for `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` types, and pulling out those with a `GenericNameSyntax` with an Identifier of `CreateRequest`.

I could then grab each of the arguments from the `TypeListArgument` of which I knew there could be 1, 2 or 3. I only wanted the instances with 3, so could read them off as `IdentifixNameSyntax` objects, and use the `Identifier` to give me the class names I needed for the `AutoMapper` maps.

I then had to lookup the names of the Classes or Enums from within the assembly using Reflection, to give me the `Type` that I could pass into `AutoMapper`.

Test Setup Code:

```
var slnPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "..", "..", "..", "MySolution.sln"));
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
_solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(slnPath).Result;
_project = _solution.Projects.First(p => p.Name == "MyProject");

foreach (var documentId in _project.DocumentIds) {
    var document = _solution.GetDocument(documentId);
    if (document.SupportsSyntaxTree) {
        _documents.Add(document);
    }
}
```

Main Code:

```
foreach (var document in _documents) {
    var methods = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>();

    foreach (var m in methods.Where(x => x.Name is GenericNameSyntax)) {
        var genSyntax = m.Name as GenericNameSyntax;
        if (genSyntax?.Identifier.Text == "CreateRequest") {
            var args = genSyntax.TypeArgumentList.Arguments;

            if (args.Count == 3) {
                var item1 = args[0] as IdentifierNameSyntax;
                var item2 = args[1] as IdentifierNameSyntax;

                if (item1 != null && item2 != null) {

                    var c1 = ReflectionTestHelper.GetClassesWithKeyword(item1.Identifier.Text).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item1.Identifier.Text)
                        ?? ReflectionTestHelper.GetEnumsWithKeyword(item1.Identifier.Text).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item1.Identifier.Text);

                    var c2 = ReflectionTestHelper.GetClassesWithKeyword(item2.Identifier.Text).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item2.Identifier.Text)
                        ?? ReflectionTestHelper.GetEnumsWithKeyword(item2.Identifier.Text).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item2.Identifier.Text);

                    if (c1 == null)
                        errors.Add("Unable to find Class for mapping :: " + item1.Identifier.Text);

                    if (c2 == null)
                        errors.Add("Unable to find Class for mapping :: " + item2.Identifier.Text);

                    if (c1 != null && c2 != null) {

                        var map = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor(c1, c2);

                        if (map == null) {

                            var location = genSyntax.GetLocation().GetMappedLineSpan();
                            var line = location.Span.Start.Line + 1;

                            var errormessage = new StringBuilder();
                            errormessage.AppendLine("No AutoMapper map found for :: " + item1.Identifier.Text + " -> " + item2.Identifier.Text);
                            errormessage.AppendLine("\tLocation: " + document.FilePath + "[Line:" + line + "]");
                            errormessage.AppendLine("\tMethod: " + genSyntax.Parent);
                            errors.Add(errormessage.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, not that nice, but it does the job.